# GoDaddy Multiple website hosted on Dedicated Server issue

Tags: hosting

I'm using my friend's dedicated server where he hosts 2 of his websites to host my own, but I'm not familiar with registering domains, and I can't get my domain to point to a specific port I use so that my website doesnt clash with his. He has 2 websites that according to IIS are using the SAME PORT, I installed XAMPP so I had to use the 8080 port, how did he register two different domains for websites hosted on the same ip under the same port? and how do i point my domain to my 8080 port? (using apache)

Comment: Are you using IIS, Apache ect?..... cannot give you any info about making adjustments without knowing the environment. The server knows which site to serve up based on the request from the client.  Its all in the headers

Answer (score 1):

You need to use host headers to prevent conflicts if you're sharing the same IP, else you need your own IP.  With the appropriate dns settings, and host headers setup in iis, you'll never conflict with his sites (that should also be using host headers).

Comment: how to i use host headers in php/apache?

Comment: it's different in IIS than Apache, but it's the same idea.  for apache you should refer to virtualhost configuration.  since this is godaddy, you dont have access to things like that, you need to use their interface.  I recommend using their support forums or wiki for documentation (http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5399/hosting-multiple-websites-on-your-hosting-account).  Having multiple sites share an ip is common practice.